# Need help using Java EE Eclipse (using src in my jsp)

Tags: eclipse, src

the situation is I already imported my java classes which are Feed.java, Feedlist.java into the src folder in my workspace.

The question is, how can I use it in my JSP? what the syntax to import it? Because I need to invoke some methods (list())to be used in my JSP.

Thanks everyone for the help

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm assuming you're trying to run your app on Weblogic or Tomcat.

I usually have my folders setup as:

```
src
web
--WEB-INF
----classes
----lib
```

I have my Tomcat pointed to my web folder, which is where the JSPs are.
Your java files should be compiled to the classes folder.
And any Jars are placed in the lib folder.

To include a class, which should be on the classpath at this point, just use:

```
<%@ page import = "java.util.*"%>
<%@ page import = "your.package.Feed*"%>
<%@ page import = "your.package.Feedlist*"%>

<%
Feed myFeed = new Feed();
%>
```

Comment: Yep, I am running in tomcat. How do I compile my java files?